# Changing DNS when I have different email and web hosts

Tags: email, redirect, hosting, domain-name-system

I've just built a new site on a NEW host at this domain www.new-domain.com

The current live site is at a different domain www.old-domain.com and different host

I want www.old-domain.com to redirect to www.new-domain.com (I have all the rewrite and redirect rules etc.)

My confusion is over what DNS records to change in order to redirect old to new AND keep email working with old domain. Here's the details:

---

1) I am creating a domain on my NEW webhost called old-domain.com this will be where the htaccess redirect rules are that will redirect users to new-domain.com

2) However, email is hosted separately and all the users will still be using username@old-domain.com

3) old-domain.com website is currently hosted with Rackspace, but won't be after the switch

4) new-domain.com email is hosted with Cobweb

5) old-domain.com nameservers are set to: NS.123-REG.CO.UK and NS2.123-REG.CO.UK

As I am only changing where the website of old-domain.com is hosted, I need to know what to change!

Here's my current DNS settings:

```
@ - MX - Priority 10 - cluster3.eu.messagel
@ - MX - Priority 20 - cluster3a.eu.message
@ - A - 1.2.3.4
@ - TXT/SPF - v=spf1 include:spf.m
autodiscover - CNAME - autodiscover.hosteds
ftp - CNAME - old-domain.
mail - A - 9.8.7.6
www - A - 1.2.3.4

Name servers: NS.123-REG.CO.UK and NS2.123-REG.CO.UK
```

The IP address 1.2.3.4 is with Rackspace (which has two records: @ and www). The other records I think are with Cobweb (email).

---

Question: If I want to point old-domain.com to the new host (Vidahost) BUT KEEP EMAIL WITH COBWEB, should I only change the 1.2.3.4 records above?

---

One of the reasons this came about is because 123-reg told me to change the nameservers to the new host - when the current setup has the nameservers set as 123-reg, so I thought changing this would throw email out! Ultimately, I'm only changing the website location.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to change your website hosting, however leave your emails where they are currently, you will need the change the IP address which your domain names A records point to for www and @.  You should leave the nameservers pointing to 123-Reg and make no changes to your MX or mail A record.

This will keep the email as it is now, and just point to your new website.

Comment: This is correct. Would just like to add one thing: Lower your TTL values before changing DNS settings. If everything goes correctly, then it will just make the transition smoother. If something goes wrong you'll be able to recover from the error quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your email on your old provider, then please just point your A record to your new hosting provider. You dont need to point your domain to your new name server.

Hope it helps